# How to capture a backgroundimage canvas and a picture which the user has uploaded?

Tags: html, css, canvas

So I have a html file which has a canvas that uses a background image. But the problem I am facing at the moment is that when a user uploads a new picture it replaces this background image. but what I want it to do is to make the users picture go behind the background image so they can then download it as one whole image.

The script uses php and js. But I am thinking this is to do with CSS and HTML. so could you please help me out :) Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="dropzone" data-download="true" data-width="594" data-height="816" data-url="canvas.php" data-resize="true" style="background-image:url(assets/images/cover_Kaplan.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
    <input type="file" name="thumb" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `lighten` option in the canvas context `globalCompositeOperation` it will give an effect of two images being merged together

Is is my jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/khqknwva/

Javascript

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var img1 = new Image;
img1.src = "http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/58650930/6/stock-photo-58650930-suspicious-cat-portrait.jpg";

var img2 = new Image;
img2.src = "http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/56467866/6/stock-photo-56467866-suspicious-cat-portrait.jpg";

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";

ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);
ctx.drawImage(img2,0,0);
```

You may need to hit the run button a few times because I haven't encoded the images. Also just a side note their are many other options for `globalCompositeOperation` here http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/

Comment: hey thanks for your help but this is not what I wanted..I want a background image which is already established by me....and then want to allow the user to upload the image. However when they upload this image because the background image will be a png file the image the image they upload will sit behind the background image.